# Writing all zeros of xe-y notation

Tags: math-mode, siunitx

I'm writing a text for people without much scientific knowledge and at some places, it would be nice to wite things like: `1 mm = 0.001 m`. 
You can probably understand, that I don't want to always manually write all thoese zeros, imagine `picogram`...

Is it possible - perhaps with `siunitx` - to write something like `\SI{13}{\pico\gram} = \SI{13e-12}{\gram}`, but getting as result `0.000 000 000 013 g` instead of `13 x 10^(-12) g`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are after `scientific-notation = fixed`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{13}{\pico\gram} = \SI[scientific-notation = fixed]{13e-12}{\gram}
\end{document}
```